# Getting Alert from ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have editable html table of user Information. There are some columns such as user_ID, branch_ID etc. when I am going to change the branch_ID of the user I want to check the particular user has tasked assigned to him or not. If he has tasks then update is not allowed. for that I am using the following java script part.

```js
              if(field=='branch_ID'){
                     $.ajax({
                         type: 'post',
                         url: 'check_user.php',
                         data: {udata: user_id},
                         success: function (data) {
                           
                        // message_status.text(data);
                           
                   
                        }
                     })

                 }
```

In check_user.php

```html
$user_id= $_POST['udata'];

$sql1="SELECT * FROM assign_task WHERE user_ID=$user_id";
$query1=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query1)>0){
    echo"you can't update";
return false;
}
else{
  echo"ok with it".$sql1;
}
```

The thing is I want the respond from check_user.php as an alert and return false to stop updating the content. As I am new to jQuery please help me.

Comment: you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). as far as what you want to do. `if (data == "you can't update") { ... }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSON to pass more complex data:

PHP :

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($query1)>0){
    echo json_encode(array("success" => false));
}
else{
  echo json_encode(array("success" => true, 
                         "message" => "ok with it".$sql1));
}
```

Javascript:

```
success: function (data) {

    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    if(jsonData.success){
         alert(jsonData.message);
    }

}
```

Remember to do more advanced checking on your variables and types first!